Pdfmerger showing wrong document
Im using pdfmerger to preview and merge my document, when i use device like pc or laptop its normal, but when use mobile its preview another document,  help me pleaseee
my iframe   




<iframe  src="<?= base_url('pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=/') ?><?= base_url('my_ctrl/my_func/'.$my_var) ?>" frameborder="0" width='100%' style="height:100vh !important" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen></iframe>


my controller





  $this->load->library('pdfmerger');
        $pdfx = new Pdfmerger;
        ob_clean();
        ob_end_flush();
        ob_end_clean();

        $pdfx->addPDF('uploads/merge/'.$waktu.'.pdf', 'all');
        

        $output2 = $this->pdf102->load_view_new('my_folder1/my_folder2/pdf/my_view', $data);

        usleep(2000);
        $waktu2 = date("YmdHis");
        $t2 = microtime(true);
        $micro2=explode(".",$t2);
        $waktu2=$waktu2.$micro2[0].$micro2[1];
        $nama2='uploads/merge/'.$waktu2.'.pdf';
        file_put_contents($nama2, $output2);      
        
        ob_clean();
        ob_end_flush();
        ob_end_clean();
        $pdfx->addPDF('uploads/merge/'.$waktu2.'.pdf', 'all');

        foreach($data['file'] as $filenya){
            ob_clean();
            ob_end_flush();
            ob_end_clean();

            $cekpdf=strpos($filenya['ALAMAT'],".pdf");
            if($cekpdf!==false){
                $pdfx->addPDF('uploads/global-init/plugins-init/jquery-file-upload/server/php/files/'.$var, 'all');
            }
            else{

            }

        }
        usleep(2000);
        $waktuz = date("YmdHis");
        $tz = microtime(true);
        $microz=explode(".",$tz);
        $waktuz=$waktuz.$microz[0].$microz[1];
        $tempat='uploads/merge/'.$waktuz.'.pdf';

        ob_clean();
        ob_end_flush();
        ob_end_clean();

        $pdfx->merge('browser', base_url('uploads/merge/'.$waktuz.'.pdf'));
        unlink('uploads/merge/'.$waktu.'.pdf');
        
        exit(0);




this is my code, where its i have to repair??, i want the preview is same like mobile and pc or another device please help me

Cache files may be stay in browser on mobile. Add a cache-busting parameter to the your iframe URL. It can ensures the browser fetches the latest file.
Modify your iframe URL:
<iframe  
    src="<?= base_url('pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=/') ?><?= base_url('my_ctrl/my_func/'.$my_var) ?>?t=<?= time() ?>" 
    frameborder="0" 
    width='100%' 
    style="height:100vh !important" 
    allowfullscreen 
    webkitallowfullscreen>
</iframe>

The ?t=<?= time() ?> adds a unique timestamp to the URL, forcing the browser to reload the file.
